# Obtaining and plotting a step plot for time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had the following dataframe containing information about stages as a time series:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Stages': ['Stage 1', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 3', 'Stage 1'], 'Start(s)': [0, 630, 780, 840, 900, 930], 'End(s)': [630, 780, 840, 900, 930, 960]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    Stages         Start(s) End(s)
0   Stage 1          0      630
1   Stage 2         630     780
2   Stage 2         780     840
3   Stage 2         840     900
4   Stage 3         900     930
5   Stage 1         930     960
```

I wanted to obtain a step plot as shown [here](https://www.sleepline.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/hypnogram.jpg) so I did this:

```
#Replacing the string stages
mapping = {'Stage 1': 1, 'Stage 2': 2,'Stage 3': 3}
DF = df.replace({'Stages': mapping})
```

This gives me

```
    Stages     Start(s) End(s)
0   1            0      630
1   2            630    780
2   2            780    840
3   2            840    900
4   3            900    930
5   1            930    960
```

Can someone please tell me how to obtain a plot such as [this](https://www.sleepline.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/hypnogram.jpg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was to use the ["steps" drawstyle provided by matploltib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html).  If you use this, you can *almost* just plot the values in the "End(s)" column - the catch is you need to prepend the first start time/stage to the list of values being plotted:

```
x = [df['Start(s)'].iloc[0], *df['End(s)']]
y = [df['Stages'].iloc[0], *df['Stages']]

plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps')
```

[image]

This is about the bare minimum; it ignores the particular formatting specific to the sleep cycle, rather it hopefully shows you how to draw the desired curve "from scratch".

---

Additional notes:

- If you need to invert the y axis, you can convert the stages to negative integers instead of positive ones.
- If you need to rename the y labels, you can use `plt.yticks([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])` to rename them.
- Generally this approach is reliant on the "stages" being interpretable as integers.  If you had additional stages that were not numeric, you would need to recode them to numbers, and then change their name using `plt.yticks` as above.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use [`yasa.plot_hypnogram`](https://raphaelvallat.com/yasa/build/html/generated/yasa.plot_hypnogram.html).

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import yasa #pip install yasa

d = {'Stages': ['Stage 1', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 3', 'Stage 1'],
     'Start(s)': [0, 630, 780, 840, 900, 930], 'End(s)': [630, 780, 840, 900, 930, 960]}

ser = (
        pd.DataFrame(data=d)
            .replace({"Stages": {"Stage ": ""}}, regex=True)
            .astype({"Stages": int})
            .assign(Time= lambda x: [list(range(i, j+1)) for i, j in x[["Start(s)", "End(s)"]].values])
            .explode("Time")
            .loc[:, "Stages"]
      )

yasa.plot_hypnogram(ser)
```

##### # Output :

[image]

> -2 = Unscored
> -1 = Artefact / Movement 0 = Wake 1 = N1 sleep 2 = N2 sleep 3 = N3 sleep 4 = REM sleep

NB : You may need to use a Python version (`>=3.7`, `<3.11`) to install all of `yasa` dependencies. Python version (`3.11.0`) seems to not be supported yet.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that this existed. However, do you know if this can only be plotted in hours? I think this is assuming that my sampling freq. is 1/30 (which IS the freq of my original dataset), but I was wondering how would we go about plotting it in durations as in the MWE.

Comment: I think this is only applicable when you have the hypnogram in a very specific format. Still useful though, thanks!